# Java anonymous generics

Tags: java, generics

When I do this, the compiler will complain.

```
  private Map<String, T> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(16, (float) 0.75, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
            return size() > capacity;
        }
    };
```

But when I do these, the compiler will accept it.

```
private Map<String, T> map = new LinkedHashMap(16, (float) 0.75, true) {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > capacity;
    }
};
```

Or

```
   private Map<String, T> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, T>(16, (float) 0.75, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
            return size() > capacity;
        }
    };
```

The entire code:

```
public class LRUCache<T> {

    private int capacity;

    private Map<String, T> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, T>(16, (float) 0.75, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
            return size() > capacity;
        }
    };


}
```

I know it may be something related to erasure. But I'm confusing about the details.

Comment: show the error message you're getting.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what type of HashMap you want to extend.